# how to create an array of object in php

Tags: php

I want to clean my old_array and split it up to array of objects. So the new_array contains string and integer.

This is my old_array named $test_temp_variable which is only in string.

```
discount_org: [
[
"{"day":"00:00"",
""time":"08:00"",
""discount":"10:00""
],
[
""day":"00:00"",
""time":"14:00"",
""discount":"10:00""
]
```

This is my desired output

```
discount_org: [
{
day: 0,
time: 8,
discount: 10
},
{
day: 0,
time: 14,
discount: 10
}
```

but is this even possible in PHP?
I have tried in several object-oriented features, but always end up not working. If yes, can you give a finger point?

var dump of my old array

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "{"day":"8:00""
    [1]=>
    string(14) ""time":"12:00""
    [2]=>
    string(15) ""discount":"10""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) ""day":"8:00""
    [1]=>
    string(14) ""time":"12:00""
    [2]=>
    string(15) ""discount":"10""
  }
```

Comment: Neither your old nor your new arrays are valid PHP structures, they seem JSON. Please issue a `var_dump` of your old array and report it here.

Comment: And show us your code

Comment: @moonwave99, i just added my var dump

Answer (score 1):

If i do understand you correctly you have to make an object for each array-index you want to have, like:

```
class Obj {
    public $Int;
    public $String;

    public function setInt($Int) {
        $this->Int = $Int
    }
    public function setString($String) {
        $this->String= $String
    }
}
```

then make some objects out of it, like:

```
$Test = new Obj();
$Test->setInt(3);
```

and add them to your array like:

```
$TestArray[] = $Test;
```

You can now access them like:

```
$TestArray[0]->Int;
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but before i can do this i have to split my string up, and put them in that i kind of a approach

Comment: @ Zaz: In order to do that, look at  http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php. With those functions you can cut your String into the pieces you need and make objects out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
  public $property1;
  public $property2;
}

$array = array();

$object1 = new MyClass;
$object1->$property1 = 0;
$object1->$property2 = 22;


$object2 = new MyClass;
$object2->$property1 = 11;
$object2->$property2 = 32;

$array[] = $object1; // This adds in order, this would be on $array[0]
$array[] = $object2; // $array[1]

// OR associative way:

$array['Object1'] = $object1;
$array['Object2'] = $object2;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your array to an array of objects using [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php):

```
$arr[] = array('day' => 0,
                'time' => 8,
                'discount' => 10);
$arr[] = array('day' => 0,
                'time' => 14,
                'discount' => 10);
$arr[] = array('day' => 1,
                'time' => 9,
                'discount' => 15);
$discount_org = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $disc){
    $item = new stdClass;
    foreach ($disc as $key2 => $val){
        $item->$key2 = $val;
    }
    $discount_org[] = $item;
}
var_dump($discount_org);
```